# How to use drawer navigator and tab navigator simultaneously?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is my tab navigator:

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" backBehavior="initialRoute">
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Science"
    component={Science}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Science',
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
        <Image source={require('../../assets/images/science-tab.png')} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

This is DrawerNavigator:

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

And this is my root navigator: Below Bottomnavigation is the tab navigator.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="BottomNavigation"
      component={BottomNavigation}
      options={{title: this.createTitle()}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

[image: So basically on the menu icon click i want to open the drawer]

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to make your `TabNavigator` a screen of `DrawerNavigator`

You can do something like this:

```
function TabNavigator({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      // Your tab screens
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="DrawerNavigator" component={DrawerNavigator} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

If you want to open your drawer, you can call `navigation.openDrawer()` in your `TabNavigator`.

## Update to address label issue

You can create a drawer content component to override the default behavior of adding the `DrawerNavigator` screens' labels as the content of the drawer.

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Home"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
      // ...
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Then you need to change the `DrawerNavigator` to this:

```
function DrawerNavigator({route}) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

So you can add new screens to your DrawerNavigator and navigate to them using the `DrawerItem` onPress function.

Of course make sure to import `DrawerContentScrollView`, `DrawerItemList` and `DrawerItem` from `@react-navigation/drawer`.

For more info look at: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent.

Comment: But the thing is I dont want to show that tab navigator label in the drawer. Instead i want to make custom drawer with new routes. Adding tab navigator in the drawer navigator screens adds a label in the drawer.